# logging in sharepoint through c# programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to login programatically to a sharepoint app and get the html code of specific page within that website.
Is there a way how I can do that programatically? 
I am having problems with the part where I need to pass the login parameters and access the url I need to get the html code.
Thanks in advance everyone, Laziale

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mysite.sharepoint.com");
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUser", "myPass");
        request.Credentials = credentials;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string html = readStream.ReadToEnd();

        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
```

Comment: This question should be moved to [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @pstrjds - This seems like more of a general programming question (despite the reference to sharepoint), I would suggest leaving it here.

Comment: @Patricker - now that I have had my coffee I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url goes here");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string html = readStream.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

Comment: I am getting 'the handle is invalid' on the 2nd line, the place where I submit the credentials

Comment: code posted, check the top of the page. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @Laziale - It seems your error is probably caused by system configuration, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950404/networkcredential-error-in-asp-net